# Remove clicked id from the input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to delete clicked id to remove input value. For example i have this input  `<input type='hidden' id='uploadvalues' value="8,9"/>` you can see the values `8,9` and the button is `<div class="delete" id="9"></div>` .
When i click  the `id="9"` then the input value 9 should be remove . After clicked `id="9"`  ==> `<input type='hidden' id='uploadvalues' value="8"/>`

How can i do that anyone can teach me?

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/oxeKLM)** from CodeCanyon

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="area">
      <div class="image"><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/05/2f/1b/052f1b3a2361eb4f3c1385c1fd4f75ed.jpg"></div>
      <div class="delete" id="8"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="area">
      <div class="image"><img src="http://www.wallpapermade.com/images/wallpapers/originals/tip-and-oh-laugh-together-home-2015-movie-wallpaper-4612.jpg"></div>
      <div class="delete" id="9"></div>
   </div>
   <input type='hidden' id='uploadvalues' value="8,9"/>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("body").on("click", ".delete", function(){
    // Remove clicked id from the input value  
   });
});
```

Comment: Using `id`s that start with a number is not recommended. I'd put it in a `data` attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way on the approach you want is

```
   $("body").on("click", ".delete", function(){
      var id = this.id, //extract the id from the clicked element
          values = $('#uploadvalues').val().split(','), // get the existing values in the #uploadvalues element
          remaining = values.filter(function(val){ // filter out the ones equal to the id of the clicked element
             return val !== id;
          });

      $('#uploadvalues').val(remaining.join()); // update the changed values 
   });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @gaby-aka-g-petrioli . So can you tell me what do you think about this solution. Please click for another solution [Demo](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/oxeKLM)

Comment: The demo works but leaves back some useless elements. The `.delete` button with the `id` attribute removed. So it becomes a junk element because it cannot function anymore.. Depends on the overall functionality of the page which is not show from your code.

Comment: @gaby-aka-g-petrioli  Hmmm, Thank you very much for your explanatory answers.

Answer (score 2):

make it

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("body").on("click", ".delete", function(){
     var val = $(this).attr("id");
     var values = $( "#uploadvalues" ).val().split(",");
     var valIndex = values.indexOf(val);
     if (valIndex > -1)
     {
         values.splice(valIndex,1);
     }
     $( "#uploadvalues" ).val( values.join(",") )
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to make use of `regular expression` at this context,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("body").on("click", ".delete", function(){
     var id = this.id;
     $("#uploadvalues").val(function(val){
        return val.replace(new RegExp(id + "\,|\,"+ id +"$"),"")
     });
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

when you click the delete button, in the callback function grab the id:

```
var valueToRemove = this.id;
// now you need to look to see if that value is inside the hidden input
var valueToRemove = this.id;

    console.log(valueToRemove);

    var values = $("#uploadvalues").val();

  if(values.indexOf(valueToRemove) >= 0){
        $("#uploadvalues").val(values.replace(valueToRemove,""));
    }
```

also its best practice to cache the dom so you dont have to constantly query it.

Is this what you wanted? and this method does not get rid of the comma within the values.